# unable to run qr scanner code due to string arguement error

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner in flutter and I was trying to create a QR scanner, while am following a tutorial I received the:

> "Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't."

The thing is both mine and his code are exactly the same yet i get that error but his runs fine

```
 void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
 this.controller = controller;
 controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) async {
 controller.pauseCamera();
 var scanData2 = scanData;
if (await canLaunch(scanData2.code)) {
 await launch(scanData.code);
 controller.resumeCamera();
 } else {
```

Comment: on which line you are getting this error?

Comment: if (await canLaunch( scanData2.code) and await launch(scanData.code)

Comment: you are receiving String in canLaunch function?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the package which provides QR and Barcode scanner you can use as per you requirement

[Install this plugin and use it its working fine](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner)

**Reference Code**

```
String barcodeScanRes;

barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
        "#FFA200", "Cancel", true, ScanMode.QR);
if (barcodeScanRes == '-1') {
} else {
   //You Can Find success response here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use .toString() method to convert String? to String or you can also change argument of the receiver from String to String?

```
void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
 this.controller = controller;
 controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) async {
 controller.pauseCamera();
 var scanData2 = scanData;
if (await canLaunch(scanData2.code.toString())) {
 await launch(scanData.code.toString());
 controller.resumeCamera();
 } else {
```